# Hat counter has lost track

Tags: bug, status-declined, winter-bash-2015

I just noticed the following on the [Code Review Winterbash leaderboard](https://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/codereview.stackexchange.com):

[image: Leaderboard lost track while counting]

Now, if my math is correct, TopinFrassi has 5 hats and rolfl has 4 hats.

Why doesn't the leaderboard agree with me here, is Hairboat's Revenge not counted while shown?

My fellow Code Reviewers blame caching, but we always blame caching. What's the verdict here?

Comment: Stop earning them so fast!! (says the mug with twice your hatcount ;-)

Comment: Showing up correctly for me, so I guess caching *is* to blame :P

Comment: Sounds like a hat trick.

Comment: @AdamDavis nope. [Hat Trick](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/hat-trick) is harder than that..

Comment: Making this status-declined which really means "wontfix", because bydesign would be a lie -- It's not awesome, but these caching inconsistencies are a necessary evil I can live with. In almost all cases, this will be correct after an F5.

Comment: What am I doing there?!? C'm'on code reviewers, gotta earn some hats!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's correct now. The moral is: it's always caching:

[image]