# Winter Bash Leaderboard showing 0 hats when hats are earned?

Tags: bug, winter-bash, caching, winter-bash-2016

Why does the [Winter Bash Leaderboard](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) show 0 hats when hats are earned? Is it due to caching?

> [image: Image 1]
>
> *(some sites are hidden)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably caching, [same as last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270887/162102).  The leaderboard has to account for changes from across the network and from all users; it's not practical for that to be up-to-the-second accurate.  Think about other site-wide items that are cached, like review counts.  This is similar.